# How does the 'return' work in a Recursive function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, recursion

Hello I'm a first year CS student attempting to understand why the return value is not '1' when using the Recursive function for example a simple Factorial function.

```
int factorial(int x) {
    if (x==1) {
    return 1;
    } else {
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
}
```

I understand the factorial algorithm part but it eventually descends until it returns 1, so how does it return the answer instead of '1'???

- Thank you to all who reply :)

Comment: Because it returns `x * factorial(x-1)` if `x > 1`.

Comment: If you pass in `2`, then the `if` is false, so it goes to the recursive case. In that case, it calls the function with `1`, which indeed returns 1. However, that return value is then multiplied by 2, because the statement was `x * factorial(x - 1)`

Comment: @ChrisMM ohhh okay, in lack of a better way to explain my understanding: it returns x * factorial(x - 1) which basically just stays there until it gathers all x values (recursively) and then in the end spits out the answer

Comment: Correct. `factorial()` keeps being called until recursively `return 1` occurs, then the recursion unwinds.

Comment: Short summary: recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.